# Get executable (.exe) methods powershell

Tags: powershell, methods, exe

I need to install an application via powershell, but the application doesn't have all the available install parameters well documented.

I have done it with libraries, by loading the libraries an getting the members of it, but I havent achieved it with an .exe,

My question is there is a way to get the methods of a .exe via powershell?.

Comment: You can't, command line switches are not exposed in the same way as public method signatures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is no.

Many executables will attempt to use common install parameters. And your odds are increased if it uses a common installer platform (MSI, InstallShield).

If it is the EXE used with an MSI, use the MSI instead as the command line arguments are effectively universal. (For some insight into what to expect from an MSI for example [you can see my answer here](https://superuser.com/questions/570598/how-to-force-uninstall-a-software-that-is-installed-by-msi-package/570620#570620) to a very different question)

If the installer is InstallShield or another common framework for building an installer, you can try common switches, or google "productName" + install.exe switches and hope they are documented somewhere.

The last option you have is to try the common help switches:

- /h
- /H
- /?
- -h
- -H
- -?
- --h
- --?
- -help
- --Help

And whatever other combinations you can think of. Often times they are documented that way.